# RegularExpression for Telephone Number validation using Razor syntax

Tags: asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

What's the `RegularExpression` for a telephone number with spaces?

Example: [4 digits] `space` [7 digits]?

Comment: Is this for searching, or validating? You may need to use anchors based on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
^[0-9]{4}+ ([0-9]{7})$
```

or:

```
^[0-9]{4} ([0-9]{7})$
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](https://regex101.com/r/sZ1tE2/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this Regex"

```
\d{4} \d{7}
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uG9nL8/1)**

**Explanation**

```
\d{4} match a digit [0-9]
Quantifier: {4} Exactly 4 times
  matches the character   literally
\d{7} match a digit [0-9]
Quantifier: {7} Exactly 7 times
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use anchors with the regex if you want to validate the telephone number in some text field:

```
^[0-9]{4} [0-9]{7}$
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vX8jP2/2).